# Strange sql error worked local but not on live server

Tags: sql, sql-server, joomla

I'am getting the following error in my sql query: Unknown column 'provincie' in 'field list'
the strange thing is my query is tested on a local server and it worked fine.

I'am developing a joomla site and making some edits to a component after testing local i update the server version of the site and it gives me this error.

```
    $query = 'UPDATE #__rbid_auctions 
        SET `googlex` = \''.$googleKeyx.'\',
           `googley` = \''.$googleKeyy.'\',
         `provincie` = \''.$resProvincie.'\',
 `woonplaats` = \''.$resWoonplaats.'\'
       WHERE `userid`= \''. $my->id . '\';';

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->loadResult();
```

I manually created the database columns on the server i also did this local.
Anybody suggestions thx in advanced

Comment: shouldn't the last line be $db->query();

Comment: make sure local and server version have same table column name its says column not found so may be spell change!

Comment: problem solved :) made a typo in another part of the script thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following method for using an update database query which uses up to date coding standards:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();     
$query = $db->getQuery(true);     
$fields = array(
    $db->quoteName('googlex') . '=' . $db->quote($googleKeyx),
    $db->quoteName('googley') . '=' . $db->quote($googleKeyy),
    $db->quoteName('provincie') . '=' . $db->quote($resProvincie),
    $db->quoteName('woonplaats') . '=' . $db->quote($resWoonplaats)
);    
$conditions = array(
    $db->quoteName('userid') . '=' . $db->quote($my->id)
);    
$query->update($db->quoteName('#__rbid_auctions'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);   
$db->setQuery($query);

$db->query();
```

If you're using Joomla 3.x then replace `$db->query();` with `$db->execute();`

Hope this helps